# Delays or delay

Tags: grammar

I am replying to a customer on Twitter in response to his product being delayed.

My reply is: *"We are really sorry for the delays, please share your contact number with us, we'll look into it."*

Should I use the singular form of delay or plural?

Comment: Singular.  Don't admit to more than one delay.

Comment: @Xanne But, we delayed it for quite a while. This person was kept on waiting for a long time. Still, should singular be used?

Comment: Well, a long delay is still a delay.  It doesn't get plural by itself.

Comment: A nice apology and even an offer of a little extra gift, something with the company logo on it, might help if it fits within the culture.

Comment: Not delays, but you can say 'long delay.'

Answer (score 3):

You would want to use **"delay" preferably.**

**"Delays"** indicates that there have been more than one and might make someone even more angry than they already are; don't give them any more reason to be angry though by using the plural *"delays"*.